# map column values to 'miscellaneous' if value counts is below a threshold - Categorical Column - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of shape ~ [200K, 40]. The dataframe has a categorical column (one of many) with over 1000 unique values. I can visualizee the value counts of each such unique column by using:

```
df['column_name'].value_counts()
```

How do i now club values with:

- value_count less than a threshold value, say, 100, and map them to, say, "miscellaneous"?
- OR based on the cumulative row count % ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract the values you want to mask from the index of `value_counts` and them map them to "miscellaneous" using [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2000, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

frequencies = df['A'].value_counts()

condition = frequencies<200   # you can define it however you want
mask_obs = frequencies[condition].index
mask_dict = dict.fromkeys(mask_obs, 'miscellaneous')

df['A'] = df['A'].replace(mask_dict)  # or you could make a copy not to modify original data
```

Now, using value_counts will group all the values below your threshold as miscellaneous:

```
df['A'].value_counts()

df['A'].value_counts()
Out[18]: 
miscellaneous    947
3                226
1                221
0                204
7                201
2                201
```

Answer (score 2):

I think need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d']})

s = df['A'].value_counts()
print (s)
a    4
b    3
d    1
c    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

If need sum all values bellow `threshold`:

```
threshold = 2

m = s < threshold
#filter values under threshold
out = s[~m]
#sum values under and create new values to Series
out['misc'] = s[m].sum()
print (out)
a       4
b       3
misc    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

But if need `rename` index values bellow threshold:

```
out = s.rename(dict.fromkeys(s.index[s < threshold], 'misc'))
print (out)
a       4
b       3
misc    1
misc    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

If need replace original column use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['A'] = np.where(df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('size') < threshold, 'misc', df['A'])
print (df)

      A
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     b
5     b
6     b
7  misc
8  misc
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution:

```
cond = df['col'].value_counts()
threshold = 100
df['col'] = np.where(df['col'].isin(cond.index[cond >= threshold ]), df['col'], 'miscellaneous')
```